# How do I create application launchers in Gnome Panel

Tags: 11.04, panel, gnome-classic

I currently use individual application launchers to create something like below for the apps I commonly use

[image]

They are tedious to create/modify as I have to move/modify 1 by 1 - Is there a better way?

**UPDATE**: I am using Ubuntu Classic, the launchers are added by "Right Click Panel > Add to Panel > Application Launcher"

[image]

Comment: We cannot help you unless you state which launcher you use and exactly how you create the launchers.

Comment: I use `add to panel > application launcher`

Comment: Please clarify further and add it to your question by editing it. You need to state which launcher you use, that doesn't look like the standard Unity launcher.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't Unity being talked about. I think these are application launchers on Gnome panels in Gnome 2. I'm pretty sure you can also drag applications onto the panels, but other than that, I don't know a quick way to add or remove applications from Gnome panels.

Comment: Why don't you just use something like dockbarx or awn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### From any menu

To add a launcher to a panel from a menu, perform one of the following steps:

- Open a menu that contains the launcher. Drag the launcher on to the panel.
- Open the menu that contains the launcher and right-click on the title of the launcher. Choose Add this launcher to panel. This method will only work if the launcher is on a sub-menu of the menu that you opened.

### From the file manager

To add a launcher to a panel from the file manager, find the .desktop file for the launcher in your file system, then drag the .desktop file to the panel.

i.e. your desktop files will be located in

- `~/.local/share/applications`
- `/usr/share/applications`

[source](http://library.gnome.org/users/user-guide/stable/gospanel-34.html.en)